# Is this expected PouchDb performance?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have a PouchDb database that contains around 32,000 documents. I am using pouchdb-find and running the following code to obtain a performance metric:

```js
const execute = async () => {
  const DATABASE_NAME = 'database';

  console.log('INITIAL          TIMESTAMP 00 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
      const pouchDatabase = new PouchDB(DATABASE_NAME, {
        revs_limit: 0,
        auto_compaction: true,
      });

  console.log('CREATED DATABASE TIMESTAMP 01 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));
      await deleteAllIndices(pouchDatabase);

  console.log('DELETED INDICES  TIMESTAMP 02 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      let indexDdoc = 'index-design-doc_' + 'TEST';
      await pouchDatabase.createIndex({
        index: {
          fields: ['dueDate'],
          ddoc: indexDdoc,
        },
      });

  console.log('CREATED INDEX    TIMESTAMP 03 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      let query = {
        selector: {
          dueDate: { $gte: null },
          ownerName: { $eq: 'Garlette, Wilma' },
          reviewer: { $eq: 'Elaine Reviewer'}
        },
        sort: [
          { dueDate: 'desc' }
        ],
        use_index: indexDdoc,
      };

  console.log('CREATED QUERY    TIMESTAMP 04 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      let results = await pouchDatabase.find(query);

  console.log('FIND             TIMESTAMP 05 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      indexDdoc = 'index-design-doc_' + 'TEST';
      await pouchDatabase.createIndex({
        index: {
          fields: ['dueDate'],
          ddoc: indexDdoc,
        },
      });

  console.log('CREATED INDEX    TIMESTAMP 06 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      query = {
        selector: {
          dueDate: { $gte: null },
          ownerName: { $eq: 'Garlette, Wilma' },
          reviewer: { $eq: 'Elaine Reviewer' }
        },
        sort: [
          { dueDate: 'desc' }
        ],
        use_index: indexDdoc,
      };

  console.log('CREATED QUERY    TIMESTAMP 07 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);

      results = await pouchDatabase.find(query);

  console.log('FIND             TIMESTAMP 08 : ' + getComparableUtcDate() + ' : ' + DATABASE_NAME);
};

execute();

async function deleteAllIndices(localTable) {
  let indices = await localTable.getIndexes();
  for (let index of indices.indexes) {
    if (index.ddoc !== null) {
      await localTable.deleteIndex(index);
    };
  };
}

function getComparableUtcDate(localDateObject = null, offsetInDays = 0) {
  let localDate;
  if (localDateObject === null) {
    localDate = new Date();
  } else {
    localDate = localDateObject;
  }

  if (offsetInDays !== 0) {
    localDate.setDate(localDate.getDate() + offsetInDays);
  }

  const utcDate = localDate.toUTCString(); // "Wed, 14 Jun 2017 07:00:00 GMT"

  const parts = utcDate.split(' ');
  const year = parts[3];
  const month = getMonthNumber(parts[2]);
  const day = parts[1].padStart(2, '0');

  const subParts = parts[4].split(':');
  const hour = subParts[0].padStart(2, '0');
  const minute = subParts[1].padStart(2, '0');
  const second = subParts[2].padStart(2, '0');

  const utcMilliseconds = localDate.getUTCMilliseconds().toString();
  const millisecond = utcMilliseconds.padStart(3, '0');

  const timezone = 'UTC';

  const comparableUtcDate = year + month + day
    + '_' + hour + minute + second + '.' + millisecond
    + '_' + timezone;

  return comparableUtcDate;
};

function getMonthNumber(monthName) {
  const truncMonthName = monthName.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();

  let monthNumber;
  switch (truncMonthName) {
    case 'JAN':
      monthNumber = '01';
      break;
    case 'FEB':
      monthNumber = '02';
      break;
    case 'MAR':
      monthNumber = '03';
      break;
    case 'APR':
      monthNumber = '04';
      break;
    case 'MAY':
      monthNumber = '05';
      break;
    case 'JUN':
      monthNumber = '06';
      break;
    case 'JUL':
      monthNumber = '07';
      break;
    case 'AUG':
      monthNumber = '08';
      break;
    case 'SEP':
      monthNumber = '09';
      break;
    case 'OCT':
      monthNumber = '10';
      break;
    case 'NOV':
      monthNumber = '11';
      break;
    case 'DEC':
      monthNumber = '12';
      break;
    default:
      monthNumber = 'xx';
  }

  return monthNumber;
};
```

I get the following output:

```js
INITIAL          TIMESTAMP 00 : 20190314_005045.585_UTC : database
CREATED DATABASE TIMESTAMP 01 : 20190314_005045.687_UTC : database
DELETED INDICES  TIMESTAMP 02 : 20190314_005045.807_UTC : database
CREATED INDEX    TIMESTAMP 03 : 20190314_005050.466_UTC : database
CREATED QUERY    TIMESTAMP 04 : 20190314_005050.466_UTC : database
FIND             TIMESTAMP 05 : 20190314_005055.343_UTC : database
CREATED INDEX    TIMESTAMP 06 : 20190314_005055.392_UTC : database
CREATED QUERY    TIMESTAMP 07 : 20190314_005055.392_UTC : database
FIND             TIMESTAMP 08 : 20190314_005059.953_UTC : database
```

which shows that it takes about 4.6 seconds to initially create the index, then about 4.9 seconds to do a find(). As expected, the second try at creating the index is almost instantaneous, since it already exists, and the second find takes about the same time as the first find. I found no difference in processing time if I added "ownerName" and "reviewer" as additional index fields.

My question is: Are these times normal for a PouchDb database using pouchdb-find? Or, have I missed something crucial in tuning its performance?

Comment: Using "table name" in PouchDB is confusing, since PouchDB doesn't have tables.

Comment: But to answer your actual question: It's impossible to say. Your index may or may not actually help your queries, since your index is only related to the `dueDate` field, but your query is against 3 fields, and your query is effectively only checking whether `dueDate` exists. This means the efficacy of your index depends on how often your `dueDate` is null. If it's never or rarely null, then your index is just a waste.

Comment: Based purely on your performance data, I would guess that your index is ineffectual, since scanning the data to build the index takes about the same time as doing the query.

Comment: Whether this is "normal" is much harder to answer. But it probably is normal, given your specific circumstances, since this is what you're observing.

Comment: @Flimzy, thanks for your feedback. I changed TABLE_NAME to DATABASE_NAME to minimize confusion. I also modified my question to document that I saw no difference in processing time if I added "ownerName" and "reviewer" as additional index fields.

Checking for "dueDate" is null was to allow it to be used as a sort field. Your 3rd comment is thought provoking. WRT your 4th comment, I am hoping to hear if someone else has a similar performance metric to quote.

Comment: Adding `ownerName` or `reviewer` as the 2nd and 3rd field of your index will have no effect on  your current query. If you make those the first and second fields, it may help.

Comment: I faced same issue. We introduced multiple pouchdb instance for each model to increase the perfomance.